# Deploying ThreeJS project based on Vite on GitHub Pages (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () )

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, github-pages, vite

I'm having problems deploying my ThreeJS project on GitHub page.
When i run the code locally with npm run dev it work fine, but deploying it on GitHub Pages gives me an error of Failed to load resource: [the server responded with a status of 404 ()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXS1F.png)

[The project][2]:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#d6d1d1">
    <canvas id="bg"> </canvas>
    <div id="app">
    </div>
    <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
canvas {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

JS Imports:

```
import './style.css';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import { FontLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/FontLoader.js';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { TextGeometry } from 'three/addons/geometries/TextGeometry.js';
import {GUI} from 'dat.gui';
```

Comment: It would help if you shared your GitHub page url. It could be a GitHub misconfiguration or it could be your project files.

Answer (score 0):

Your local directories are way different from your production deploy directories.

First, I would recommend to generate a production build in your PC, try them locally, and then upload those production build files/directories to github pages.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML in the github repo is serving your `main.js` files with an absolute url.

```
<script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
```

This is a problem because your github pages url is:

```
https://username.github.io/project/index.html
```

and when the HTML file tried to download the `main.js` file it goes to the url:

```
https://username.github.io/main.js
```

but the file is located at:

```
https://username.github.io/project/main.js
```

Try changing you script src to a relative url

```
<script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
```

and see if it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here I recently came across this situation and I figured out that.

1. Follow the Vite configuration and static page deploy step-by-step.
2. After finishing your git actions config you can use your ThreeJS code like this:

   This is how your main file may look:

> ```
> import "./style.css";
> import setupThree from "./three";
>
> document.querySelector("#app").innerHTML = `
>   <canvas class="webgl">
>   </canvas>
> `;
>
> setupThree(document.querySelector(".webgl"));
> ```

This is how your setup may look:

> ```
> import * as THREE from "three";
>
> function setupThree(element) {
>   const canvas = document.querySelector(".webgl");
> }
>
> export default setupThree;
> ```

Them you can just use the cube tutorial from threeJS.

This is my first post here :D hope I can help.